# NgbDatePicker : Focus on Input box

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am not able to focus on the `input` box (on `click`/`focus`), instead it focuses on the calender popup. When i press tab or click on the `ngbDatePicker` input box, it opens the `calendar`, and focus is on the today's date (or whichever selected). As a result, It doesn't let me type the date by keyboard.

But what i want is to focus the input box, even if the calendar is open, so that i can type the date directly.

I have tried focusing through javascript, but it is not working.

```
<input
    id="dateOfBirthInput"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Datepicker"
    name="date_of_birth"
    [(ngModel)]="user.date_of_birth"
    ngbDatepicker
    required
    [minDate] = "minDate"
    #dob="ngbDatepicker"
    (click)="dob.open();"
    (focus)="dob.open();"
/>
```

I tried opening the datepicker from angular component, but it is not working.

```
<input
    id="dateOfBirthInput"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Datepicker"
    name="date_of_birth"
    [(ngModel)]="user.date_of_birth"
    ngbDatepicker
    required
    [minDate] = "minDate"
    #dob="ngbDatepicker"
    (click)="focusDateOfBirthInput();"
    (focus)="focusDateOfBirthInput();"
/>

//component code
@ViewChild("dob") dob: NgbDatepicker;

focusDateOfBirthInput() {
    console.log("focusDateOfBirthInput");
    document.getElementById("dateOfBirthInput").focus();
    console.log(this.dob);
    this.dob.open()
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround to achieve what you want please try this:

1. Inject renderer using constructor like this and import it as well from 
   @angular/core

   constructor(private renderer: Renderer)
2. And then update your input element like this:

Explaination: I have taken another input reference named "inputRef" and will take it in component.ts file as ViewChild.

3. Take the reference of input element via "ViewChild" and implement the method with settimeout

   @ViewChild('inputRef') inputRef;
     constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {
     }

   focusOnInput(datePickerRef) {
       datePickerRef.open();
       setTimeout(() => {
         this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inputRef.nativeElement, 'focus');
       }, 10)
     }

And bingo, I tried and Tested, It will work.

Comment: I have seen the example, but it is not helping my case. Have you read my question and understood it?

Comment: Yes I understood your question, Let me summarise it so that we are on the same page:

When Clicked/Tab on the input box, and it doesn't focus on the input element and It opens the date selection modal with today's date selected by default and hence, You are not able to type the date.

Comment: Yes, thats right, how can i allow my users to type in the input box, with calendar open as well

Comment: I updated the answer, please try the solution, I tried and it's working for me.

Comment: I used an alternative solution, but i will give your solution a try and confirm

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti what is your alternative solution? Can you provide it? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @AhmedHasn. Its been so long, i dont remember the code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```js
public change(el,dael){
  dael.open();
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(el);
    el.focus()
  },500);

}
```

```html
<input
    id="dateOfBirthInput"
    type="text"
    (click)="change($event.target,dob);"
    (focus)="change($event.target,dob);"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Datepicker"
    name="date_of_birth"
    [(ngModel)]="user.date_of_birth"
    ngbDatepicker
    required
    [minDate] = "minDate"
    #dob="ngbDatepicker"
    
/>
```

Comment: I used an alternative solution, but i will give your solution a try and confirm

Answer (score 0):

here is a working solution for

- ng-bootstrap 9.0.2
- Angular 11

Other versions not tested.

We need `ngZone` so that the `datepicker` popup is not "re-focused" if the date-input is focused.

```
    // (...)
        
        @ViewChild('datePicker') datePicker: any;
        
       //  (...)
        
        constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
        
        public toggleDatePicker(): void {
            this.datePicker.toggle();
            if (this.datePicker.isOpen()) {

         this.ngZone.onStable.asObservable().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
                const elementToFocus = this.datePicker._elRef.nativeElement;
                if (elementToFocus) {
                  elementToFocus.focus();
                }
              });
            }
          }
```

in template

```
     <input type="text"
               #datePicker="ngbDatepicker"
               ngbDatepicker
               (click)="toggleDatePicker()" 
               (...)
    />
```